# Update labels of a tree depending on ancestors of nodes in linear time

Tags: algorithms, trees, graph-traversal

> You are given a tree $T=(V,E)$ along with a designated root node $r \in V$.The parent of any node $v \ne r$, denoted $p(v)$, is defined to be the node adjacent to $v$ in the path from $r$ to $v$. By convention, $p(r) = r$.
>
> For $k > 1$, define $p^k(v) = p^{k−1}(p(v))$ and $p^1(v) = p(v)$ (so $p^k(v)$ is the $k$-th ancestor of $v$).
>
> Each vertex $v$ of the tree has an associated non-negative integer label $l(v)$. Give a linear-time algorithm to update the labels of all the vertices in T according to the following rule: $$l_{new}(v) = l(p^{l(v)}(v)).$$

This is problem 3.20 in Dasgupta's Algorithm.

My thoughts so far:

1. The problem comes down to how you find the $l(v)$-th parent of a node $v$, for all $v \in V$, in linear time.
2. Since chapter 3 is about depth first search, I'm trying to use it. The only way to get the parent once we have the child is to do something in the post-visit routine

   ```
   explore(v): 
     v.visited = true
     previsit(v)
     for all u adjacent to v:
       if u.visited == false:
         explore(u)
     postvisit(v)
   ```
3. If $l(v) = 3$ then somehow we need to send this information up 3 levels in the recursion. But depth first search only moves one level at a time. I don't know how we can preserve the information across multiple calls.

Comment: Remember to upvote posts that help you.

Comment: Hi @Raphael I did upvote your answer but it appears I need 15 reputations for my vote to be publicly displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how we can preserve the information across multiple calls.

Excactly; we use a standard trick of functional programming and add additional parameters to the recursion.

**Idea:** Store (a copy of the) call stack in an array. Then, all ancestors of the current node are accessible in $O(1)$ time. You can do BFS or DFS.

**Details:** The main procedure starts at the root and creates an empty array of sufficient size:

```python
relabel(T : Tree) {
  relabelH(T, 0, new Tree[T.size])
}
```

The second parameter stands for the current index in the array (i.e. recursion depth) which we use to determine the index of the $k$th ancestor. The actual work is done here:

```python
relabelH(T : Tree, level : Int, ancestors : Tree[]) {
  ancestors[level] = T
  T.label = ancestors[max(0, level - T.label)].label

  for c in T.children {
    relabelH(c, level + 1, ancestors)
  }
}
```

*Correctness*: You can show by induction that `ancestors[0..level-1]` always contains the current node's ancestors in order from root to parent. Hence, the label update is correct. All nodes are reached (we do DFS) so the procedure is correct.

*Running time:* Every line in `relabelH` is executed once per visited node. Every individual line runs in constant time, assuming a reasonable implementation of `Tree`. The main call `relabel(T)` takes linear time (array initialization) plus the cost of the call to `relabelH`. In total, we get a running time in $\Theta(n)$ with $n$ the number of nodes (`T.size`).

Comment: Of course, once you have made the node history explicit, you no longer need recursion. I kept it for clarity; real implementation would use a loop for efficiency.